# Angular library build watch broke modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

For my job, I'm developing an Angular (16.2) library that is used in an application.

Since transitioning from Angular 15 to 16, we have an issue when using it via

```
ng build my-lib --watch --configuration development.
```

After investigating, it appears that the modules generated via the watch mode sometimes produces faulty code.

For exemple i just modified an enum used in the library [diff before & after watch update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhwhI.jpg)

Do you have any idea what could be causing this issue? Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

I've tried modifying various compilation options, i've updated to the latest version of Angular 16 and i reproduced this in a small project... You can reproduce this :

1. [Get the project](https://github.com/t0m-4/lib-build-watch/tree/main/projects/my-lib)
2. Run 'ng build my-lib --watch --configuration development'.
3. Check the file my-workspace\dist\my-lib\ui\form\form.module.d.ts
4. Update the file my-workspace\projects\my-lib\ui\form\models\form-type.model.ts (for exemple set another value for the enum value 'Other'
5. Check again the file my-workspace\dist\my-lib\ui\form\form.module.d.ts, some imports disappeared.

Maybe it's related to my code but I don't understand why.
Thank you

Comment: I see you just opened an issue on the angular repo : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51483

Comment: yes I managed to reproduce the problem on a small project and it seems to me to be a bug

Comment: Do you have a solution ?